# What can trace of $TT^*$ say about $T$

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

I was reading a solution of this question

> Let $T:V \to V$ and $\|T\|=2\|T^*\|$ over inner product space, then $T=0$

The author solves it when he shows that $tr(T^*T)=0$ and then chooses an orthogonal basis $B$ of $V$ then defines $A:=[T]_B$ and shows that

$$trace(A^*A)=\sum_{i,j}|a_{ij}|=0$$ And therefore $T=0$.

My question is, is there a generalized theorem that given $T,trace (T^*T)$ that can say something about what $T$ looks like?

Comment: Are you familiar with the singular value decomposition (SVD)?

Comment: @mathreadler No, it's covered next semester.

Comment: Okay. Anyway, it will give insight into what $A^*A$ looks like in a general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head, there are two useful facts about $\operatorname{tr}(T^*T)$.

**Fact 1:** The function $\|T\|_F = \sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(T^*T)}$ defines the "Frobenius norm", also known as the Hilbert-Schmidt norm.  Moreover, this norm is induced by the inner product $\langle S,T \rangle = \operatorname{tr}(T^*S)$.  This leads to the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$
|\operatorname{tr}(T^*S)|^2 \leq \operatorname{tr}(S^*S)\operatorname{tr}(T^*T)
$$

**Fact 2:** In general, we have
$$
\operatorname{tr}(T^*T) \geq \sum_{j=1}^n |\lambda_j(T)|^2
$$
and this equality is attained if and only if $T$ is a normal matrix (i.e. $TT^* = T^*T$).

Comment: In **fact 2**, are $\lambda_j$ distinct eigenvalue of $T$ or can they be non-distinct?

Comment: They can be non-distinct